# How should a server implement middlewares chaining?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, event-loop

I'm struggling a lot trying to understand the logic behind the ExpressJS module, in particular i'm focusing on the implementation of the middlewares chain.

My objective here is to understand how is it possible to implement the logic of a server listening for requests, and once arrived, passes the request packet through an array of functions each of which:

1. should be able to **modify the packet** for the next middleware
2. should be able to **send the response** back but it should not prevent other middlewares to respond as well, so **there should be only one response at the end of the chain** (i guess)
3. should access some function to call in order to run the **next** middleware in chain, but without the need to pass it the request and response parameters (e.g. just calling "**next( )**" )

#### Note on point 1

I imagine that with languages like javascript is possible to pass the object around using concepts like closure, but i would like to understand it in a language-independent way and use javascript features only if it provides clever ways to handle it simply, otherwise i'll write the logic as i was using any other language.

So my big questions are:

1. How should the request handling be implemented?
2. How do i allow every middleware to modify the packet?
3. How do i pass the updated packet to the next middleware?
4. How do i implement the "next" function to pass to every middleware?

Thank you

Comment: It's honestly a bit hard to pin down what exactly you're asking.  Perhaps if you want to know how ExpresJS works, you should just go look at [the code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/lib).  Lots of the statements in your question are a bit off from how things actually work.  For example, there's no need to call `setTimeout(middleware, ...)` to delay anything.  Incoming requests are processed via the event queue as they arrive, one at a time unless an existing request does something asynchronous in which case other requests can do some work during that slack time.

Comment: This is very broad, but one thing that might help to know is that the event-loop doesn't really call middlewares, it's just a chain of functions calling each other. I found it _really_ helpful to understand middlewares better by implementing my own. It ends up fitting in around 20 lines of code: https://github.com/curveball/core/blob/master/src/application.ts#L47

Comment: @jfriend00 i know i apologize, ok, setTimeout aside, i need to understand how to implement the request handling, so how do i allow to every middleware to modify the packet, and how do i pass the updated packet to every middleware in the chain?

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, this is how a chain of middlewares with a next function can be called.

```
function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
   // do something with req or res
   next();
}

const mws = [
  myMiddleware,
  anotherMiddleware
];

/**
 * Calls a chain of middlewares.
 *
 * mws is an array of middlewares
 */
function callMwChain(req, res, mws) {
   if (mws.length === 0) {
     // We're done here
     return;
   }

   /**
    * Take the first middleware
    */
   const firstMw = mws[0];


   /**
    * Call it, and give it a next function that continues the chain
    */
   firstMw(req, res, () => {
      callMwChain(req, res, mws.slice(1));
   });

}
```

I've written this as a recursive function, but it can also be rewritten as stack. This is easier though.

Express middlewares have a lot of bonus magic, so their implementation is going to be more complex, but this is broadly how it works.

Note that there's no event-loop in sight.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little working server that supports middleware and GET routes.  It uses a similar calling convention on the route handlers as Express `(req, res, next)`, but has far, far, far fewer features than Express.  But, hopefully you can see how the dispatch function cycles through the routes, advancing to the next route only if the previous handler calls `next()`.

You can actually run this code and define routes and play with it (though it is definitely barebones basic):

```
const http = require('http');

function dispatch(req, res, array, index, cb) {
    console.log(req.method, req.url, array, index);
    if (array && array.length > index) {
        let item = array[index];
        if (!item.path || item.path.toLowerCase() === req.url.toLowerCase()) {
            item.fn(req, res, function() {
                // previous route called next(), so we advance to the next item in the array
                ++index;
                dispatch(req, res, array, index, cb);
            });
            return;
        }
    }
    cb();
}

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // incoming request here, initiate calling the middleware
    dispatch(req, res, server.middleware, 0, function() {
        if (req.method === "GET") {
            dispatch(req, res, server.gets, 0, function() {
                // done with gets here, apparently didn't send a response
                res.statusCode = 404;
                res.end();
            })
        } else {
            // ... fill in code for other methods here
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.end();
        }
    });
});

// server route implementation
// save arrays for each type of route handler
// upon a request, run all the middleware requests, then advance
// to the routes for the right type of request and see if any of them
// match the URL.  If so, run them.
server.middleware = [];
server.gets = [];
server.posts = [];

server.use = function(fn) {
    server.middleware.push({path: "", fn: fn});
}

server.get = function(path, fn) {
    server.gets.push({path, fn});
}


// route definitions
server.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    req.myCustom = "hi";
    next();
});

server.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.myCustom);
    next();
});

server.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.write("Hello World");
    res.end();
});

server.listen(80);
```

Comment: @DamienzOnly - So, two of us have written simple examples that show middleware routing. But, we haven't heard anything from you.  Do these give you an idea how it can work?